# Top integral cohomology of configuration spaces of plane

Tags: algebraic-topology, reference-request, homology-cohomology

Let $C_{k}(R^{2})$ be a k-points unordered configuration space of euclidean plane. It is a well known result of Arnold that the integral cohomology groups of degree bigger than $k$ is zero. My question is that what is the degree of top non-trivial integral cohomology group of the space $C_{k}(R^{2}).$ I found the paper "Integral cohomology of configuration spaces of sphere" by Christoph Schiessl. In this paper, she computed degree of top integral cohomology of $C_{k}(R^{2})$ for $k<18.$ is there any formula for all $k$?

Comment: That's the same thing as the top cohomology of the complement of the braid arrangement. Searching using those terms wou will find papers by Stanley and others studying the S_n module structure on it and, in particular,  their dimension.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Not quite, the braid arrangement is the ordered configuration space. But you should be able to extract the unordered answer, at least with $\mathbb{Q}$ coefficients, from the papers you cite.

Answer (score -2):

This isn’t a full answer, but we have that $k$ is an upper bound for this top cohomology, as $C_k(\mathbb{R}^2)$ has the homotopy type of a CW complex of dimension less than or equal to $k$.

To see this, as per Mariano’s comment, we identify this space with the complement of the braid arrangement of hyperplanes in $\mathbb{C}^k$. Intuitively, interpret $\mathbb{R}^2$ as the complex plane, and note that unordered $k$ tuples are exactly degree $k$ monic polynomials with distinct roots, giving the connection to algebro-geometric objects.

Anyway, once we know our space is the complement of some union of hyperplanes in $\mathbb{C}^k$, we know it is the complex points of an affine variety. Then an incredible theorem of complex/algebraic geometry gives that it is homotopic to something of at most dimension $k$, giving the upper bound.

Comment: The upper bound k is already mentioned in the question. This is proved by Arnold in his classical paper.

Comment: Ahh my mistake, here is just another way to see the upper bound holds!